# Not able to exchange message between a pair of unix socket client server to exchange messages randonly

Tags: c, linux, sockets, process, pthreads

I am trying to establish a unix socket communication between a pair of client and server, where client and server will be two different processes running on same machine and client will receive input from command line which it will pass to server and server will then respond with a buffer. Both should be able to communicate randomly in both way. To achieve this, I opened sockets at both end and waited in an infinite loop to recv from other end. However, at client side once I start waiting in the infinite loop for recv I am not able to send command line instruction to server, I always get blocked in the loop. If I send command line instruction first to server then I am not able to recv anything from server. Similar at server as well. I trued using select() call but it also waits in infinite loop to get FD_SET and recv, so again stuck in same situation. I also tried making different threads at client for sending and recieving, however again I am stuck in recv since it always waits in infinite loop. Can anyone please suggest the efficient mechanism to achieve this.

```
Code snippet is as below:

#####################################################CLIENT######################################
void* msimcli_RecvFromSocket(void *)                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                       
   int msglength = 0;                                                                                                   
   int result = 0;                                                                                                      
   char buffer[CLI_MAX_BUF_SIZE];                                                                                       
   pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "CliRcThd");                                                                      

   printf("\nWait in Rx on socket descriptor %d\n",datagramSocket.fd);                                                  
   do{                                                                                                                  
      result = select(datagramSocket.fd + 1, &datagramSocket.rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);                                   
   }while(result == -1 && errno == EINTR);                                                                              

   if (result > 0){                                                                                                     
      if (FD_ISSET(datagramSocket.fd, &datagramSocket.rset))                                                            
      {                                                                                                                 
         printf("FD SET Rx on socket descriptor %d\n",datagramSocket.fd);                                               
         /* The socket_fd has data available to be read */                                                              
         msglength = recv(datagramSocket.fd, buffer, CLI_MAX_BUF_SIZE, 0);                                              
         if (msglength == 0) {                                                                                          
            /* This means the other side closed the socket */                
             close(datagramSocket.fd);                                                                                   
         }                                                                                                              
         else if(msglength > 0){                                                                                        
            printf("Message received at cli\n");                                                                        
            printf("Rcvd string = %s\n",(char*)buffer);                                                                 
            /* TBD */                                                                                                   
            //return 1;                                                                                                 
         }                                                                                                              
      }                                                                                                                 
   }                                                                                                                    
   else if (result < 0)                                                                                                 
   {                                                                                                                    
      /* An error ocurred, just print it to stdout */                                                                   
      printf("Error on select(): %s\n", strerror(errno));                                                               
   }                                                                                                                    
}               

int msimcli_SendToSocket(void* buf)                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                       
   int rc = ROK;                                                                                                        
   /*Test buffer*/                                                                                                      
   cliCmd *buff = (cliCmd *)buf;                                                                                        
   printf("Buff %s\n", ((cliCmd *)buf)->buf);                                                                           
   for (int i = 0; i < buff->hdr.msglen; i++)                                                                           
   {                                                                                                                    
    printf("[%x]", buff[i]);                                                                                            
   }                                                                                                                    
   printf("\n");                                                                                                        
   printf("sending on socket [%d]\n",datagramSocket.fd);                                                                
   rc = sendto(datagramSocket.fd, buf, buff->hdr.msglen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&datagramSocket.remote, datagramSocket.len);
   if (rc == -1) {                                                                                                      
      printf("%s: errno=0x%x %s\r\n", __FUNCTION__,errno, strerror(errno));                                             
      printf("SENDTO ERROR\n");            close(datagramSocket.fd);                                                                                         
      return 0;                                                                                                         
      //exit(1);                                                                                                          
   }                                                                                                                    
   else {                                                                                                               
      printf("Data sent!\n");                                                                                           
      return rc;                                                                                                        
   }                                                                                                                    
}
int msimcli_ConnectToSocket(const char* socketFile,int isSockTypeStreaming,SOCKET_PARAMS* socketParam)
{                                                                                                                       
   int rc = ROK;                                                                                                        
   int result = 0;                                                                                                      
   char      buffer[CLI_MAX_BUF_SIZE];                                                                                  
   int       buffer_size = CLI_MAX_BUF_SIZE;                                                                            
   socklen_t len;                                                                                                       
   MSIM_ZERO(*socketParam);                                                                                             
   pthread_t snd_tid;                                                                                                   
   pthread_t rx_tid;                                                                                                    

   if (isSockTypeStreaming)                                                                                             
   {                                                                                                                    
      socketParam->type = SOCK_STREAM;                                                                                  
   }                                                                                                                    
   else                                                                                                                 
   {                                                                                                                    
      socketParam->type = SOCK_DGRAM;                                                                                   
   }
   socketParam->fd = socket(AF_UNIX, socketParam->type, 0);                                                             
   if (0 > socketParam->fd)                                                                                             
   {                                                                                                                    
      rc = RFAILED;                                                                                                     
      goto Exit;                                                                                                        
   }                                                                                                                    
   else                                                                                                                 
   {                                                                                                                    
      printf("socket created successfully with socket descriptor %d\n",socketParam->fd);                                
   }                                                                                                                    
   socketParam->remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;                                                                            
   strcpy(socketParam->remote.sun_path, socketFile);
   socketParam->len = strlen(socketParam->remote.sun_path) + sizeof(socketParam->remote.sun_family) + 1;
   FD_ZERO(&socketParam->rset);                                                                                         
   FD_SET(socketParam->fd, &socketParam->rset);
   /* Create Receiver thread */                                                                                         
   if(ROK != (rc = pthread_create(&rx_tid,NULL,msimcli_RecvFromSocket,NULL)))                                           
   {                                                                                                                    
       printf("Thread create for Receiver failed\n");                                                                   
       goto Exit;                                                                                                       
   }
Exit:
   if (ROK != rc)    {                                                                                                                    
      printf("%s: errno=0x%x %s\r\n", __FUNCTION__,errno, strerror(errno));                                             
      if (-1 < socketParam->fd)                                                                                         
      {                                                                                                                 
         close(socketParam->fd);                                                                                        
         socketParam->fd = -1;                                                                                          
      }                                                                                                                 
   }
   printf("<< rc %d\r\n", rc);                                                                                          
   return rc;                                                                                                           
}

int msimcli_ConnectToSocket(const char* socketFile,int isSockTypeStreaming,SOCKET_PARAMS*  socketParam)
{                                                                                                                       
   int rc = ROK;                                                                                                        
   int result = 0;                                                                                                      
   char      buffer[CLI_MAX_BUF_SIZE];                                                                                  
   int       buffer_size = CLI_MAX_BUF_SIZE;                                                                            
   socklen_t len;                                                                                                       
   MSIM_ZERO(*socketParam);                                                                                             
   pthread_t snd_tid;                                                                                                   
   pthread_t rx_tid;                                                                                                    

   if (isSockTypeStreaming)                                                                                             
   {                                                                                                                    
      socketParam->type = SOCK_STREAM;                                                                                  
   }                                                                                                                    
   else                                                                                                                 
   {                                                                                                                    
      socketParam->type = SOCK_DGRAM;                                                                                   
   }
   socketParam->fd = socket(AF_UNIX, socketParam->type, 0);                                                             
   if (0 > socketParam->fd)                                                                                             
   {                                                                                                                    
      rc = RFAILED;                                                                                                     
      goto Exit;                                                                                                        
   }                                                                                                                    
   else                                                                                                                 
   {                                                                                                                    
      printf("socket created successfully with socket descriptor %d\n",socketParam->fd);                                
   }                                                                                                                    
   socketParam->remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;                                                                            
   strcpy(socketParam->remote.sun_path, socketFile);
   socketParam->len = strlen(socketParam->remote.sun_path) + sizeof(socketParam->remote.sun_family) + 1;             
   FD_ZERO(&socketParam->rset);                                                                                         
   FD_SET(socketParam->fd, &socketParam->rset);
   /* Create Receiver thread */                                                                                         
   if(ROK != (rc = pthread_create(&rx_tid,NULL,msimcli_RecvFromSocket,NULL)))                                           
   {                                                                                                                    
       printf("Thread create for Receiver failed\n");                                                                   
       goto Exit;                                                                                                       
   }                                                                                                               
Exit:
   if (ROK != rc){
      printf("%s: errno=0x%x %s\r\n", __FUNCTION__,errno, strerror(errno));                                             
      if (-1 < socketParam->fd)                                                                                         
      {                                                                                                                 
         close(socketParam->fd);                                                                                        
         socketParam->fd = -1;                                                                                          
      }                                                                                                                 
   }
   printf("<< rc %d\r\n", rc);                                                                                          
   return rc;
}

##########################################SERVER##########################################

       while(1)                                                                                                             
       {
          do{
             FD_ZERO(&rset);
             FD_SET(serverDatagramSocket, &rset);
             result = select(serverDatagramSocket + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
          } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
          if (result > 0) {
             if (FD_ISSET(serverDatagramSocket, &rset)) {
                /* The socket_fd has data available to be read */
                msgLength = recv(serverDatagramSocket,buffer,CLI_MAX_BUF_SIZE, 0);
                if (msgLength == 0) {
                   printf("MsgLength zero, other side closed the socket\n");
                   /* This means the other side closed the socket */
                   close(serverDatagramSocket);
                }
                else if (msgLength > 0){
                   printf("MsgLength nonzero, message received on socket[%d]\n",serverDatagramSocket);
                   recvdCli.hdr.msglen = ((cliCmd *)buffer)->hdr.msglen;
                   recvdCli.hdr.msgtype = ((cliCmd *)buffer)->hdr.msgtype;
                   uint16_t buff_len = (recvdCli.hdr.msglen - sizeof(recvdCli.hdr));
                   strncpy((char *)recvdCli.buf, (char *)((cliCmd *)buffer)->buf, buff_len);
                   recvdCli.buf[buff_len] = '\0';
                   printf("hdr length : %d\n", recvdCli.hdr.msglen);
                   printf("hdr msgtype : %d\n", recvdCli.hdr.msgtype);
                   printf("buffer length : %d\n", buff_len);
                   printf("buffer : %s\n", recvdCli.buf);
                   /* Test send */
                   //FD_CLR(serverDatagramSocket,&rset);
                   macsim_SendDatagram((void*)str);
                   //return 1;
                }
             }
          }
          else if (result < 0) {
             /* An error ocurred, just print it to stdout */ 
                printf("Error on select():%s\n",strerror(errno));
       else if (result < 0) {
          /* An error ocurred, just print it to stdout */
          printf("Error on select(): %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
       }
    Exit:
       if (NULL != buffer)
       {                                                                                                                    
          free(buffer);                                                                                                     
       }                                                                                                                    
       if (-1 != serverDatagramSocket)                                                                                      
       {                                                                                                                    
          close(serverDatagramSocket);                                                                                      
          serverDatagramSocket = 1;                                                                                         
       }                                                                                                                    
       printf("<<rc = %d\r\n", rc);                                                                                         
       return rc;                                                                 
    }          

    int macsim_SendDatagram(void *buffer)                                                                                   
    {                                                                                                                       
       int rc = ROK;                                                                                                        
       /*Test buffer*/                                                                                                      

       printf("MACSIM Test Buffer is %s\n", (char*)buffer);                                                                 
       printf("\n");                                                                                                        

       printf("Trying to send on socket descripor [%d]\n",macsimDatagramSocket.fd);                                       
       rc = sendto(macsimDatagramSocket.fd, buffer, strlen((char*)buffer), 0, \                                             
             (struct sockaddr *)&macsimDatagramSocket.remote, macsimDatagramSocket.len);                                    
       if (rc == -1) {                                                                                                      
          printf("%s: errno=0x%x %s\r\n", __FUNCTION__,errno, strerror(errno));                                             
          printf("SENDTO ERROR\n");                                                                                         
          close(macsimDatagramSocket.fd);                                                                                   
          return 0;                                                                                        
       }                                                                                                                    
       else {                                                                                                               
          printf("Data sent!\n");                                                                                           
          return rc;                                                                                                        
       }                                                                                                                    
    }     



**Ouputs as follow:**

***Output at server:***
--------------------------------------------------------------
/*************************************************/
Open server socket
>>
>> socketFile=/dev/shm/sockets/logClient
Got opened with sock[6]
<< sock 6
Serever socket created with fd = 6
--------------------------------------------------
MsgLength nonzero, message received on socket[6]
hdr length : 13
hdr msgtype : 0
buffer length : 5
buffer : test1
MACSIM Test Buffer is TC Rcvd

Trying to send on socket descripor [6]
macsim_SendDatagram: errno=0x6b Transport endpoint is not connected
SENDTO ERROR


***Output at client:***

root@adkumar:/home/adkumar/git/5G_DU/src/macsim/bin# ./cli 
Start cli
socket created successfully with socket descriptor 3
<< rc 0

*********************************
                MENU               
***********************************
    1)runtest()                    
    1)stoptest()                    
    2)rerunlasttest()               
    0)exit()                         
Enter option from above menu:
Wait in Rx on socket descriptor 3
1
Enter TC to run
test1
Buff : test1
sending on socket [3]
Data sent!

*********************************
                MENU               
***********************************
    1)runtest()                    
    1)stoptest()                    
    2)rerunlasttest()               
    0)exit()                         
Enter option from above menu:1
Enter TC to run
test2
Buff : test2
sending on socket [3]
msimcli_SendToSocket: errno=0x6f Connection refused
SENDTO ERROR
```

Comment: You really need a complete, compilable, (non) working example; if you want any useful feed back here.   While you posted a lot, I doubt anybody wants to spend an hour trying to piece together something that could possible run, especially since it might work because they didn’t make mistakes you did.   That said, does your linux system have ClamAV, or any other “protection” software running?   These abominations like to interfere with sockets.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to provide a more pointed information in the following question Can you please check:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010875/unix-datagram-socket-is-sending-message-to-itself-instead-of-remote